# Regex for Extracting numbers from this pattern "channelId=4;5;66&"

Tags: .net, regex

I need to extract a list of numbers from a url that are delimited by a semicolon

The pattern of url is `channelId=4;5;66&fromdate=04-Aug-2015&todate=08-Aug-2015`

The list could be any amount of numbers in length (Subject to max length of a url)

so far i've got this `((;\d{1})|(;\d{2})|(\d{1};)|(\d{2};))` but this will not match the last number in the 'channelId' parameter

Comment: What regex tool are you using?

Comment: http://www.regexr.com/  to craft it - but will be used in .net code when i've got it right

Comment: What are exact values are you after? If you need to parse a query string in .NET, you can make use of [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx), and get the values of the params you need.

Comment: You're right, i'm being an idiot

Comment: I will add my answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this lookbehind regex:

```
(?<=channelId=|;)\d+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iK1xZ2/1)

Comment: That works and i've know idea how :) so i'll mark it as the correct answer, however i'll be doing what @stribizhev suggested and use some .net BCL stuff to do it instead.

Comment: `(?<=channelId=|;)` is a lookbehind assertion that makes sure `\d+` is either preceded by `channelId=` OR `;` thus giving you all the matched numbers.

Comment: Also +1 for highlighting the regex101 tool.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET, you can leverage the [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx) top parse a query string.

> The `ParseQueryString` method uses UTF8 format to parse the query string In the returned `NameValueCollection`, URL-encoded characters are decoded and multiple occurrences of the same query string parameter are listed as a single entry with a comma separating each value.

Example use from the MSDN:

```
NameValueCollection qscoll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring);

// Iterate through the collection.
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<br />");
foreach (String s in qscoll.AllKeys)
{
   sb.Append(s + " - " + qscoll[s] + "<br />");
}
```

Note you will need to reference `System.Web` (in System.Web.dll) and also add `using System.Collections` for the `NameValueCollection`.

Here is an example of getting `channelId`:

```
var querystring = "channelId=4;5;66&fromdate=04-Aug-2015&todate=08-Aug-2015";
var qscoll = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring);
var channelId = qscoll["channelId"];
```

[image]

Comment: Upvoted as that's what i'm now using, though since i didn't mention .NET in my original question, the marked answer is technically the correct one. Many thanks for pointing out the idiocy of my ways :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could search for the whole sequence of numbers and then split the result on each semicolon:

```
a = 'channelId=4;5;66&fromdate=04-Aug-2015&todate=08-Aug-2015';
m = /channelId=(\d+(;\d+)*)/.exec(a)[1].split(';');
alert(m);
```